# Segmentation Fault in my Quick Sort Program in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I'm Getting **Segmentation fault** by debugger in `partition()` function at commented variable...following code is a complete implementation of *Quick Sort* algorithm.

```c
// Sorting Algorithms

void quick_sort(int arr[],int length);
int partition(int a[],int low, int high);
void quick_sort_recursion(int arr[], int low, int high);
void swap(int *x, int *y);

void quick_sort(int arr[],int length){
    quick_sort_recursion(arr,0,length-1);

}

void quick_sort_recursion(int arr[],int low, int high){

    if(low<high){
        int pivot_value = partition(arr,low,high);
        quick_sort_recursion(arr,low,pivot_value - 1);
        quick_sort_recursion(arr,pivot_value+1,high);
    }
}

int partition(int arr[], int low, int high){

    int pivot_value = arr[high]; //getting 'segmentation fault' here
    int i = low;

    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] <= pivot_value){
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i],&arr[high]);
}
```

[see image here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaxeM.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is impossible for anyone to say for sure what the problem is from one line of code (we are not magicians). Please provide complete code as a [mre]. As a new user please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: While it is impossible to answer as given, as @kaylum stated, the most likely scenario is that `high` is equal to or larger than the size of the array pointer to by `arr[]`, meaning that the value being indexed is off the end of the array.  We would need to see the function call code to be certain, however.

Comment: You can use [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function in C, which is C standard implementation of [`Quick Sort Algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Answer (score 0):

In the image, the `high` value (`6422295`) is quite large as for the size of array. The large size array would lead to the segmentation fault.